# Adding functions to Solana contract

Tags: spl-token

Is there a repository somewhere with ways to add abi functions like on erc20 tokens?

Reflections, taxes on buy/sell transfers and contract swaps at certain amounts, automated burns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the spl-token-2022 program, which makes it easy to add "extensions" to your tokens and customize the functionality of your mint.  Some of these include transfer fees, confidential transfers, etc.

If you want to add more functionality, you can fork the code, make your change, and deploy a new program. Or you can send a PR to get your extension integrated.

Note that adoption of new token programs on Solana is very difficult, since you need buy-in from all dapps and wallets. For that reason, I'd recommend trying to include it in the Solana Labs deployment of the program.

You can find the full list of extensions at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions and the source code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program-2022

Answer (score -2):

check out these GitHub repos.
JavaScript:
https://github.com/lucky-gru/TaxedERC20

Solidity:

1. https://github.com/Prekomandir/ERC20-taxes-reflections-autoliquidity-deflationary
2. https://github.com/Prekomandir/ERC20-taxes-reflections-autoliquidity-deflationary

Incase you just need a boiler plate repo:

https://github.com/lisun85/BoilerPlate--ERC20

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).